# Ignore version number while generating RPM in gradle using nebula

Tags: gradle, rpm

I am generating RPM using nebula package in gradle. From the below code RPM gets generated named **conf-unspecified-2020.01.30.3.noarch.rpm**. Instead i wanted to remove the version number(unspecified in this rpm) from rpm name and wanted the rpm looks in a format **conf-2020.01.30.3.noarch.rpm** and this **2020.01.30.3** should be the release number. Can anyone have idea on this and Thanks in Advance!

```
task rpmpackage(type: Rpm){
        packageName "${rpmName}"
        release "${getDate()}.${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        os LINUX
        addParentDirs = false

        from("${projectDir}${repoSrcDir}") {
            into "${destDir}"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`rpm` packages need to have a version number and a release number, separated by a dash, so I don't think you can produce a package without a version number or a release number:

```
<name>-<version>-<release>.<architecture>.rpm
```

This is what you can play with.